# An error occurs in clr import.[python.net]

Tags: python, python-3.x, clr, python-3.9, python.net

When I import clr I get an error.

Environment

- pythonnet version: 3.0.1
- Python version: Python 3.9.7

Import clr.

```
import clr
```

I get an error.
I would like to know how it works properly.

```
C:\Users\user\pythonnetProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/user/pythonnetProject/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\pythonnetProject\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import clr
  File "C:\Users\user\pythonnetProject\venv\lib\site-packages\clr.py", line 6, in <module>
    load()
  File "C:\Users\user\pythonnetProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pythonnet\__init__.py", line 143, in load
    if func(b"") != 0:
  File "C:\Users\user\pythonnetProject\venv\lib\site-packages\clr_loader\types.py", line 64, in __call__
    return self._callable(ffi.cast("void*", buf_arr), len(buf_arr))
RuntimeError: cannot call null pointer pointer from cdata 'int(*)(void *, int)'
```